# Please provide extra feedback on answers by low-rep users

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I'm rather untrusting of the accuracy of answers provided by low reputation users. They're not always inaccurate, but they are sometimes. By contrast, if I see an answer by a high reputation user, their answer may or may not be what I'm after (probably because there's something wrong with my question), but I don't have to worry about them being incorrect.

Can other members of the community please be especially active in giving feedback in one way or another (voting on the answer, commenting, voting on comments belong to the answer, or providing a competing answer if necessary) when the answerer is low reputation?

This question is kind of the polar opposite of ["Hide" user to reduce bias assessments](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/hide-user-to-reduce-bias-assessments) , and is related to [Please explain downvotes ... on answers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/please-explain-downvotes-on-answers) and [Let’s vote often!](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134/let-s-vote-often)

Comment: I think part of the hesitancy to give up-votes to answers comes from the fact that down-votes only take off -2 rep.  We don't really want people getting too much rep if they're going to post bad answers, so I think that *we need to carefully read the posts that we get from new users*.  I've been a member for less than 100 days, and up-votes were quite hard to get at first, but that helped me learn how to refine answers and make them more useful.  Anyway, having gone through the tedium of being a new member, I agree that feedback is very helpful.  Even now, it's nice to have feedback on posts.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to kindly correct wrong answers? I'm seeing a few and doing my best, but I don't feel like I'm doing it nicely enough. (I'm choosing not to downvote as well, maybe I should?)

Comment: @Sjiveru If you ask me, I think that kindly correction uses softer language, like `I believe that __ would not be correct` or some other kind of non-confrontational language.  Some people, whether because English is their second language, or they are annoyed use direct language: `__ is wrong.`  That can be misinterpreted as confrontational, which is exactly what I think we should try to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

As a low-reputation user whose interest in Japanese is more of a hobby than anything else, I'd like to add my support to this idea.

When I first joined JL&U, my intention was to only ask questions, and never to try answering; I didn't want to accidentally spread misinformation due to my comparatively low skill level, especially when we are fortunate enough to have actual, native speakers whose knowledge is incomparably more useful.

However, I have tried to provide [answers](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/how-to-say-how-do-you-say/30469#30469) to [one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32167/is-there-p-in-japanese/32171#32171) or [two](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24405/what-is-the-direct-translation-of-%e3%82%86%e3%81%a3%e3%81%8f%e3%82%8a%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-in-english/24406#24406) questions where I was reasonably certain that I could provide a correct reply. Some of these answers received helpful comments, such as this:

> It's probably worth slightly editing this answer to make it clear to OP it's relation to ゆっくり**する** specifically – [sqrtbottle](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/9185/sqrtbottle)

...and this:

> 「サッポロ」, along with so many place names in Hokkaido, comes from Ainu, not Japanese. We can't let the kanji fool us. – [l'électeur](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/4032/l%c3%a9lecteur)

I'm certainly not upset by this kind of feedback - I am aware of my own limitations, and I really do appreciate constructive criticism from anyone whose grasp of the language is better than my own.

**tl;dr:** Adding comments to answers provided by low-reputation users doesn't just warn those *viewing* the answer about any mistakes - it also helps the user *providing* the answer, by letting them know which parts of their understanding are (in)correct.